# How to get the columns index from datatable which column name contains like 'ColumnName'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatables

I have a datatable which contains columns created dynamically:

```
Name | Role | Comm w1 | Role | Comm w2 | .... | Total Comm |
```

I want to get all columns index which contains `Comm`.

The expected result should be:

```
2
4
...
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried.  We are here to **help**, not do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear on what you want the output to be, whether you just want to print the positions of the columns to screen, or store them in a way to use them later.

Furthermore, this is a very simple solution.. if it wasn't for that then I wouldn't be participating.. so for future reference please provide what you have tried and what you are expecting.  It helps all that are involved in trying to help you find a solution.  Please reference ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you experience any trouble.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable { Columns = { "Name", "Role", "Comm w1", "Comm w2",  "Total Comm"}};


        foreach(DataColumn column in dt.Columns){
            if(column.ColumnName.Contains("Comm")){
                Console.WriteLine(column.Ordinal.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}


// Output:

// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know is a simple question but I'm only asking about how to get the indexes of a column which contains ColumnName. After achieving this I can decide if I want to print them or store in a List<int>, but it doesn't come to the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ to do this fairly easily.

First we need to cast the Columns to DataColumn because LINQ needs it to be `IEnumerable<DataColumn>` but Columns is `DataColumnCollection`. Then constrict the columns to ones that contain "Comm", then select the ordinal of each column, then make that a list.

```
List<int> columnIndexes = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(column => column.ColumnName.Contains("Comm"))
    .Select(column => column.Ordinal).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should do what you need

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
{
       if (col.ColumnName.Contains("Comm"))
       {
         var index = col.Ordinal;          
       }
 }
```

But as mentioned, it is best if you attempt something first.

Comment: That wouldn't work so well, the variable should be declared outside the loop and probably be a list so you would use `listIndex.add(col.Ordinal);` That way after the loop the values are still accessible, and you have all of them, your code the index is lost as soon as the if finishes due to scope issues.

Comment: @Andrew Based on what the user said they wanted.. there is no need to store values at all.. the OP just wants the index position of the column printed to screen.. not saved for *possible* further manipulation.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Lets be honest here, the question is far from the best one, they never specified their output needs in any way at all, but Wheels73's solution doesn't output or save, it sets the value only as long as the scope exists, which isn't long.

Comment: @Andrew I agree. I was just simply pointing out that *technically* none of our answers are correct since the OP was unable to explicitly provide what they want as an outcome.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I erred on the side of greatest usefulness, assuming they will later want to use those indices to access the data in those columns, but yes OP does need to read the guides here about how to ask a question.

Comment: To be honest, I was just about to go home and so I wasn't providing a whole solution to populate a list... I was just showing how to get to the index from the column name...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are right, it will get you what you are asking for, but I don't think how they use them is quite right. I would do something like this:

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
{
    if (column.ColumnName.Contains("Comm"))
    {
      indexes.Add(column.Ordinal);          
    }
}
```

This way you have the list of indexes afterwards to use however you wish.